# Background jobs in Django

Tags: python, django, twitter

I want create twitter-parser, using tweepy - thats ok. But also, i want use django for save and list results. First of all, i met with problem - import my models to the file with parser.

project_path/app_path/daemon.py - how import models? Or maybe for this operations in Django existing more logical way (for some background jobs, but with django)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, append `project_path` to `sys.path` so python can import it:

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.append('/path/towhere/myproject/') 

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'project_path.settings'

from app_path.models import *

#write your cron job.
```

I think you need to run schedule jobs, the better way to make it is by writing [custom command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/),  here is an example of such implementation: https://github.com/tivix/django-cron

Comment: Please explain why there need append, two times? And Thank you.

Comment: the second path `sys.path.append('/path/towhere/myproject/project_path')`  is not needed if your `deamon.py` inside an app, sorry, I'll commet it off.

Answer (score 1):

The preferred way of writing sripts to interact with django is by creating a [custom management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/).  These will allow you to create a command line program that lets you interact with django. Django provides a very simple framework for doing this, and it is clearly explained in the documentation above.
So you could easily set this up as a cron job.

If you are looking for a real time solution to process background jobs, [Celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org:8000/en/latest/getting-started/introduction.html) is an excellent choice.